# How do I test a promise catch block - with with an error thrown from the callback

Tags: node.js, jasmine

In node 6, is there way to test using jasmine a promises catch block for example :

```
try{

    Promise.resolve(someFunction()).then(response => {
        callback(response);
    }).catch(err => {
       //never here
    });
} catch (err => {
  //always getting to here
}
```

The test would look like this.

```
sandbox.stub(js, 'someFunction').callsFake(() => {console.log ('calling fake method'); throw new Error('uh no!')});
```

Would like to test what happens if an error is caught within the promise, will this catch block catch all errors here, from the somefunction to the invocation of the callback? And how can I test it?

T.I.A

Answer (score 0):

Just test a case where your `someFunction` throws an error.

For sequential promise calls, the catch will catch any rejected promise

This is an example:

```
const divideByZero = function(num,den){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        if(den == 0){
            reject('can not divide by zero !!');
        }
        else{
           resolve(num/den);
        }
    });
}

divideByZero(2,0)
.then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log('Reject catched');
    console.log(err)
});

Promise.resolve(divideByZero(2,0)).catch((err)=>{
    console.log('Reject catched');
    console.log(err)
})

divideByZero(2,0)
.then((res)=>{
    console.log(res);
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log('Reject catched');
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Edited my question - I am using the sinon library to force throw an exception from someFunction - however it never gets into the .catch of the promise but always bubbles up to the parent catch belonging to the parent try catch. any ideas?